# Go into UEFI from initial setup Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, boot, uefi, lenovo-laptop, clonezilla

I've bought 15 new laptops (Lenovo Ideapad 330-15AST). I want to set them all up, so I've completely configured one (in audit-mode) and then I want to use Clonezilla. I know there are pros and cons on using Clonezilla instead of MDT (I've read them all on different forums), but I know Clonezilla very well and I have been using it for years for Linux installations. I can also just use my existing Clonezilla Server and don't have to buy anything new.

When I boot a new laptop, I can't go into UEFI, to customize some settings (boot order a.s.o.). I first need to go through the initial setup procedure where I need to give my name, connect to the network and all this kind of steps. Then I can do SHIFT+REBOOT to go into UEFI.

Going into Audit mode on every laptop and doing SHIFT+REBOOT takes a very long time IMO. Also during the setup procedure I can't go into command prompt by pressing CTRL+F10.

FN+F2, during booting doesn't work either. It boots directly into the "Windows First Setup Procedure".

So my question is: **Is there an easier and faster manner to go into the UEFI settings on these new laptops that takes a couple of seconds?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are looking for the
[Lenovo Advanced Settings Utility](https://toolscenter.lenovofiles.com/help/topic/asu_lenovo/asu_main.html):

> You can use the Lenovo Advanced Settings Utility (ASU) to modify firmware settings from the command line on multiple operating systems, such as ESX/ESXi, Linux, VMware, Windows, and Windows PE. ASU supports BIOS code, Remote Supervisor Adapter, Remote Supervisor Adapter II, and Baseboard Management Controller firmware.

This is a heavy utility that you will need to study on how to use and will need
to prepare a boot environment for using it, either Linux or WinPE.

I can't help having a niggling suspicion that it might be faster to reset the
UEFI on all the computers manually one-by-one.

Comment: Or even remove the drives to clone them.